# How to merge two collections in MongoDB: Transaction and Taxes

Tags: node.js, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have 2 collections Transaction and Taxes.

Example the models are:

```
Transaction
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5cff102b4ef90140801af1e9"),
    "totalPrice" : 3.32,
    "number" : 17,
    "__v" : 0,
    "taxes" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5cff104b4ef90140801af211"),
            "tax" : ObjectId("5b60ba0b6e7a8a3a101ea73a"),
            "taxAmount" : 0.21,
            "taxBase" : 1,
            "percentage" : 21
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5cff104b4ef90140801af210"),
            "tax" : ObjectId("5bb1932f2db234342831f99e"),
            "taxAmount" : 0.11,
            "taxBase" : 1,
            "percentage" : 10.5
        }
    ]
}

Taxes
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b60ba0b6e7a8a3a101ea73a"),
    "name" : "IVA",
    "percentage" : 21
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5bb1932f2db234342831f99e"),
    "name" : "IVA 10.5",
    "percentage" : 10.5
}
```

I want to consult and as a result, return me

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5cff102b4ef90140801af1e9"),
    "totalPrice" : 3.32,
    "number" : 17,
    "__v" : 0,
    "taxes" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5cff104b4ef90140801af211"),
            "tax" : {
                "_id" : ObjectId("5b60ba0b6e7a8a3a101ea73a"),
                "name" : "IVA",
                "percentage" : 21
            },
            "taxAmount" : 0.21,
            "taxBase" : 1,
            "percentage" : 21
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5cff104b4ef90140801af210"),
            "tax" : {
                "_id" : ObjectId("5bb1932f2db234342831f99e"),
                "name" : "IVA 10.5",
                "percentage" : 10.5
            }
            "taxAmount" : 0.11,
            "taxBase" : 1,
            "percentage" : 10.5
        }
    ]
}
```

My query is so far

```
db.getCollection('transactions').aggregate(
[{
        "$match": {
            "_id": ObjectId("5cff102b4ef90140801af1e9")
        }
    },
    {
        "$lookup": {
            "from": "taxes",
            "let": {
                "pid": "$taxes.tax"
            },
            "pipeline": [{
                "$match": {
                    "$expr": {
                        "$in": ["$_id", "$$pid"]
                    }
                }
            }],
            "as": "taxes"
        }
    }
])
```

But my result is

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5cff102b4ef90140801af1e9"),
    "totalPrice" : 3.32,
    "number" : 17,
    "__v" : 0,
    "taxes" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5bb1932f2db234342831f99e"),
            "name" : "IVA 10.5",
            "percentage" : 10.5
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5bb1932f2db234342831f99e"),
            "name" : "IVA 10.5",
            "percentage" : 10.5
        }
    ]
}
```

It does not bring me the fields outside the fiscal model, "taxAmount", "taxBase" and "percentage". Why this happens and I do not get the relationship of the relationship in the agregate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to merge two arrays using [$map](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/index.html) with [$filter](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/index.html). To combine both objects you can use [$mergeObjects](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/mergeObjects/index.html) and since `$filter` returns an array you can use [$arrayElemAt](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayElemAt/index.html) to get the first item. Try:

```
db.transaction.aggregate([
    {
        "$match": {
            "_id": ObjectId("5cff102b4ef90140801af1e9")
        }
    },
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: "taxes",
            localField: "taxes.tax",
            foreignField: "_id",
            as: "taxDetails"
        }
    },
    {
        $addFields: {
            taxes: {
                $map: {
                    input: "$taxes",
                    as: "t",
                    in: {
                        $mergeObjects: [
                            "$$t",
                            {
                                tax: {
                                    $arrayElemAt: [
                                        {
                                            $filter: {
                                                input: "$taxDetails",
                                                as: "td",
                                                cond: {
                                                    $eq: [ "$$td._id", "$$t.tax" ]
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }, 0
                                    ]
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            "taxDetails": 0
        }
    }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/0nwHTLCN-p_)